# Local language and SEO friendly urls in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with renaming urls for local language in Ruby on Rails 4. I am writing all apps (backend) in English, I think its good practise. For frontend I just use local language, but problem is in Rails 4 that I don't know how to rename URls to local language.

I have url like this **www.website.com/users/1** . I am using resources :users in routes.rb. I found as '' part, but it changes all paths as well.

So when i am using routes for Germany language:
**resources :users as 'Benutzer'**  then i have to change all paths in backend to benutzer_path etc.. and this is what i don't want. It should still be user_path in backend. How i can do this?

The second question is I want to use friendly urls. I use the example with users, and I want to write all users from any town, url will generally looks like this: **www.website.com/towns/id/users/id**

And it's not nice for many reasons. How i can change this to something like this: **www.website.com/town_name/user_name**  ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [route_translator](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator) gem for this task.

You have just to wrap your routes you want to be localized in a `localized` block, and add translations to your locale files.

For friendly urls, you can use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Edit:
Considering your comment, you can use `path` in your routes:

```
resources :users, path: 'betnuzer', path_names: { new: 'schaffen', edit: 'bearbeiten' }
```

Then you can use `users_path`, etc in your backend, and your routes are translated.

Comment: Thanks for help. Friendly_id looks nice, but route_translator is something different. It add fr/de/es language to url. If i uderstand it correctly, when i will use my website only in germany language, i will have prefix /de/ in all urls. It's not what i need. I have my website in one language, but the language is different then language in code.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need.